# Multiple whois lookup

Tags: bash, for-loop, whois

I have the below script for whois lookup

```
for line in $(cat ips.txt)
do
echo $line
whois $line | grep OrgName | awk '{print $2,$NF}' 
done
```

I am having the output

```
192.168.1.1
Internet Authority
```

How can I achieve the output in the below format ?

```
192.168.1.2 : Internet Authority
```

> DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu 
> DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04 
> DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal 
> DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"

Comment: I don't get that behavior. What OS are you using? Maybe something like `whois $line | grep OrgName | awk -v LINE=$line '{print $2,LINE}'` is what you want though?

Comment: @user3783243 Your answer worked for me , but why does it provide an output like that as i mentioned in the question , its not the intended output if im not wrong

Comment: I don't get that output on a mac.. Not sure in what scenario that output would occur. I can post my solution but that won't answer the question of why it is behaving as it is. You'll likely need to provide the OS and version for users to assist with that question.

Comment: Perhaps you have some unprintable characters (such as `\r`) in ips.txt. Can you check it with `od` or `hexdump` ?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin , there is nor carriage return , i double checked it using hexdump . The output seem unintended , I cant understand the reason for that unusual behaviour

Comment: @JoelDeleep Neither can I. I don't get that output on a openSUSE Linux.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I got the issue , even though I posted the correct code, back in my server I had a typo.

Comment: `echo $line` writes it with a return, so you get 2 lines then with the subsequent whois call. If you do not want the return, do `echo -n $line`. You will then probably need a trailing whitespace for readability

Comment: You should use RIRs RDAP servers instead of whois. Far easier to parse correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the 'echo $line' line, the shell was asked to print the value of $line. The shell says ok  - done.
Then the shell moves on to the next line, that basically says 'get string then pipe it to some string manipulation and print result'.

I believe 'print something on the screen' was asked from the shell twice, 1 by echo 2 by awk, which are from 2 separate lines , so the shell behaved as expected.

To prevent this you can contain the second line in $(), so that echo will print "$line + $(whatever comes out here)"

```
for line in $(cat ips.txt)
do
echo $line : $(whois $line | grep OrgName | awk '{print $2,$NF}')
done
```

Comment: Great answer! Reading lines with `for i in $(..)` is an [antipattern in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). A `while IFS= read -r line` loop is preferred. [bashfaq how to read a file line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)